# SCA Gulp Error when Deploying to Netsuite

Tags: npm, gulp, netsuite, suitecommerce

When trying to deploy from my IDE (VS Code) to Netsuite using the gulp deploy command I am getting the following error:

[image: gulp error log]

I am using the Vinson release of SCA, and when using the NPM install command I get a lot of warnings regarding out of date dependencies, I have checked this using NPM outdated command and have updated the packages to a later release.

It looks like it gets to the SASS compiling and then errors in parse.js file, I'm assuming that a value is not getting set up which relates to the undefined error. I don't particularly want to be editing the gulp files, I'm sure it's related to the versioning of some packages.

The usual gulp commands work fine, it's just the deploy that is erroring out.

Any help would be much appreciated, I need to get this uploaded for the client!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One idea that springs to mind is to check the version of the installed SASS module to that in package.json, see if they're the same, and if not then just change package.json accordingly.

Second to this, maybe reinstall that module?

Or could there be linking issues with SASS in distro.json?

This is mostly speculation by the way, and giving answers based on memory experience of the platform.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm really late to the party but for future reference, I think you are using a newer version of node, and it fails to parse old modules on SCA.
Following node versions should be used for older versions of SCA:

- Denali 0.12.18
- Montblanc/Vinson/Elbrus 4.4.7
- Kilimanjaro 6.11.5

You'll get a lot of warnings, but not sure if updating the node modules is a good idea since there are a lot of dependencies, and that would probably take a lot of time.

If you stumble upon an error that says something on "xml2js not being able to parse" just run the following commands (inside the project's folder).

cd node_modules/xml2js/node_modules

rm -f -r xmlbuilder

npm install xmlbuilder@2.4.6

cd ../../../

And you're good to go!